# Path Markup Syntax in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I use this code to define two quarter circles:

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="300" Margin="50" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Path Name="Test1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" s:Contacts.ContactDown="Test1_PreviewContactDown" s:Contacts.PreviewContactDown="Test1_PreviewContactDown" Data="M25,0 A25,25 90 0 1 50,25 l-25,0 Z" Fill="Orange" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Path Name="Test2" s:Contacts.ContactDown="Test2_PreviewContactDown" s:Contacts.PreviewContactDown="Test2_PreviewContactDown" Data="M50,25 A25,25 90 0 1 25,50 l0,-25 Z" Fill="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" />

        <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"  Width="100" Height="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"></Ellipse>
    </Grid>
```

Now I'd like to extend this code, so that instead of two quarter circles with cover half a circle, I'd like to have 6 circle segments which each 30 degrees. How can I do that? I wasn't really able to understand the [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).

Comment: Just wondering, why not use the designer view and let it generate the xaml?

Comment: Even with Blend i wasn't able to draw areally 30 degree circle segment:S

Comment: As the MSDN doc page on the path markup syntax linked to in this question doesn't seem to exist any more, the [.NET 4.0 version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can be used now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with VoodooChild above that your best bet is to use a visual designer like Expression Blend.  You can get a free trial from Microsoft.  You can just make the path you want and copy the generated XAML into whatever page you are authoring.

Also, doing a little googling, I found this:

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/jasema-the-xamlpadx-plugin-for-building-path-geometry/

Which looks like a free Path builder plugin for XAMLPadX.  I haven't tried it myself, but suffice to say that there is no magical easy way to make Paths in WPF without using a tool.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of Blend, but even with Blend i wasn't able to draw areally 30 degree circle segment:S